# how i solve http error in panda .jupytar note book?

Tags: python, pandas

i try to read csv with panda in jupytar note book i try every thing but not work
the caode
df_census=pd.read_csv(r"https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u8xnd9uz7wdya4r8j0tYoV0LHAQ1x-4H/view?usp=sharing.csv")

df_census=pd.read_csv("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u8xnd9uz7wdya4r8j0tYoV0LHAQ1x-4H/view?usp=sharing.csv")

df_census=pd.read_csv("https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/November/5a0a554c_u.s.-census-data/u.s.-census-data.csv.")

any help please ??

Comment: can you describe the error and what is blocking you

Comment: http error i try alot of things really